# RestTemplate with proxy - how to test

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, resttemplate

I have this piece of code:

```
HttpRoutePlanner routePlanner = new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(new MyProxySelector());

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory 
    = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
        HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyUrl, port))
            .build());
restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```

How can I create a test class to verify that the restTemplate is using the actual proxy?

Best regards.

Comment: One option that I am still working on is using test containers to test against. You could spin up a squid container and test against it.

Comment: [creating-simple-proxy-server-with-go](https://reintech.io/blog/creating-simple-proxy-server-with-go). You also can try to create a webserver using nginx and watch whether there are incoming requests to nginx.